# Frontier points counter example

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The boundary points of union of two sets is a subset of boundary points of 1st set union boundary points of second set.
That is if $A$ is topology on $X$ then
$$Fr(A\cup B) \subseteq Fr(A) \cup Fr(B)$$

I need a counter example in which
$Fr(A\cup B)$ is not a subset of $Fr(A) \cup Fr(B)$

Comment: Please use MathJax to format questions on this site.  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference  You'll get a lot more help and fewer down votes if you show that you have made an effort to solve the problem yourself.  What have you tried?

Comment: Actually im not a tech guy thats why i face some problem in writing and asking questions ...i am math guy. I will try my best to understand the format. And tell you what my hobby is doing math so i always try first before asking. And i want to share my work my effort via pic but 2mb??? A restriction.

Comment: If you right-click on any math text (an equation or expression) you'll get a popup menu that gives you some options on how to display the math.  If you choose "as Tex commands" you'll see the MathJax.  That's really helpful, because you can look at questions similar to the one you want to ask.  Also, if click on the "edit" button under your question, you'll be able to see how F.A. reformatted it.  MathJax is much preferred to images, as images aren't searchable.

Answer (score 1):

If $Fr(A\cup B) \subseteq Fr(A)\cup Fr(B)$ is always true, then you can't find an example where that doesn't happen.

I suppose you are asking the oposite: an example where $Fr(A)\cup Fr(B)$ is not a subset of $Fr(A\cup B)$.

In that case in $\mathbb{R}$, pick $A = (1,3)$ and $B = (2,4)$.

We have $Fr(A) = \{1,3\}$ and $Fr(B) = \{2,4\}$

So $Fr(A)\cup Fr(B) = \{1,2,3,4\}$ which is not a subset of $Fr(A\cup B) = \{1,4\}$

Comment: You are great. So nice of you